# RestEasy create token with expiration

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I have to create  web services requires creating a token, That Which expires in a few minutes, but I have no idea how to create a session or some kind of persistence RestEasy

Comment: the solution that can make a timer was, and register it in the singletons of the structure of jboss, sorry for the late reply: D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a [preProcesorInterceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/interception/PreProcessInterceptor.html) ,  you will generate the token and will maintain it in memory (maybe using a Map)  or database storing also the expiration time, so in the preprocesor you will check if the token is still valid.